# How to create .war file using jenkins for deployment

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, war

I started working on Jenkins for continuous integration. My java project is build successfully but am not able to find .war file for deployment. If I manually keep the myproject.war file inside workspace auto deployment is happening in tomcat7.

Now my question: is Jenkins able to create .war or not (if any extra plugins are needed please let me know), or if i need to add any build.xml file where can i keep this file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which build tool do you use (ant, maven, gradle, ...)?

Comment: i am using ant build tool

Comment: Do you have a target defined in the build.xml that generates the war? is this target activated by the Jenkins build?

Comment: yes i have a target in my build.xml but i am confusing the location of build.xml file and i want to know is any extra configurations are required for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i find the solution,
Jenkins is not having a feature like auto creating .war file.
so we have to create build.xml (ANT) for creating .war file.
Keep this file in your project and check-in into the repository.
And map the build.xml location in Jenkins  configuration page.  When the build is happen through Jenkins  it will take the code from repository build it and stores in workspace in Jenkins folder along with .war file. 
You can do auto deploy this .war file into your tomcat using Jenkins.

Comment: Hi @Kamal Gadepalli, Actually we are also facing the same issue, we got strut at creating build.xml (ANT) which creating .war file, so could you please provide some link or explain us in detail like how to create the build.xml file which create .war file